# Left-Right Join operator in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am migrating my oracle db to SQL Server 2008.In oracle we can use =(+) operator to indicate left or right joins. In SQL Server is there a operator to indicate left or right joins? Should we always code as LEFT JOIN ... ON ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` in my opinion.

- it's clearer from the statement what you're doing
- it's the ANSI standard for JOINs in any SQL-based relational db system
- it works on various systems, other than any proprietary extensions like the += and =+ in Oracle

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific operator like that - you should use the explicit `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` notation.

Answer (score 1):

The old `*=` syntax was removed from SQL Server in 2005. To use it set the compatibility level to 80.